# Problem with adding new view in my ASP.NET Core project

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a really weird problem that I can't solve. I've created controllers and a couple of views and they all work fine.

I have `HomeController` and I added a

```
public IActionResult Contact()  
{ 
    return View(); 
}
```

method that returns the view `Contact`.

When I modified my `.cshtml` file and started my app, it cannot find my css and js files and images but on other views it works fine. I already checked all href and src attributes they are all correct (I put same values for src and href in other views and it works fine).

Here are a few screenshots so you can see what I am talking about:

[My new method for returning Contact View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFEjT.png)

[Example of my Home Index view code where all works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS01Q.png)

This is my `Contact.cshtml` file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Kontakt";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@section Styles{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="~/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/contact_responsive.css">
}

<!-- Home -->

<div class="home">
    <div class="home_background parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/contact.jpg" data-speed="0.8"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="home_container">
                    <div class="home_content">
                        <div class="home_title">Contact</div>
                        <div class="breadcrumbs">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li>Contact</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Google Map -->

<div class="map">
    <div id="google_map" class="google_map">
        <div class="map_container">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Contact Form -->

<div class="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="review_form_container">
                    <div class="review_form_title">get in touch</div>
                    <div class="review_form_content">
                        <form action="#" id="review_form" class="review_form">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between">
                                <input type="text" class="review_form_input" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                                <input type="email" class="review_form_input" placeholder="E-mail" required="required">
                                <input type="text" class="review_form_input" placeholder="Subject">
                            </div>
                            <textarea class="review_form_text" name="review_form_text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            <button type="submit" class="review_form_button">send message</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Contact Text -->

<div class="contact_text">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Contact Info -->
            <div class="col-lg-5">

                <div class="contact_info">
                    <div class="contact_title">contact info</div>
                    <div class="contact_info_content">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="contact_info_icon"><img src="images/contact_info_1.png" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="contact_info_text">Rosia Road, no67, Gibraltar UK</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="contact_info_icon"><img src="images/contact_info_2.png" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="contact_info_text">office@yourbusiness.com</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="contact_info_icon"><img src="images/contact_info_3.png" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="contact_info_text">+45 7703 29293 34</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact_info_social">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- FAQ -->
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="faq">
                    <div class="contact_title">faq</div>
                    <div class="faq_content">

                        <!-- Accordions -->
                        <div class="accordions">

                            <div class="accordion_container">
                                <div class="accordion d-flex flex-row align-items-center"><div>Kako da kupim proizvod?</div></div>
                                <div class="accordion_panel">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis quam ipsum. Pellentesque consequat tellus non tortor tempus, id egestas elit iaculis. Proin eu dui porta, pretium metus vitae, pharetra odio. Sed ac mi commodo, pellentesque erat eget, accumsan justo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="accordion_container">
                                <div class="accordion d-flex flex-row align-items-center"><div>Kako da napravim profil?</div></div>
                                <div class="accordion_panel">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis quam ipsum. Pellentesque consequat tellus non tortor tempus, id egestas elit iaculis. Proin eu dui porta, pretium metus vitae, pharetra odio. Sed ac mi commodo, pellentesque erat eget, accumsan justo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="accordion_container">
                                <div class="accordion d-flex flex-row align-items-center active"><div>Proin eu dui porta, pretium metus vitae?</div></div>
                                <div class="accordion_panel">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis quam ipsum. Pellentesque consequat tellus non tortor tempus, id egestas elit iaculis. Proin eu dui porta, pretium metus vitae, pharetra odio. Sed ac mi commodo, pellentesque erat eget, accumsan justo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Newsletter-->
<div class="newsletter">
    <div class="newsletter_content">
        <div class="newsletter_image" style="background-image:url(images/newsletter.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="section_title_container text-center">
                        <div class="section_subtitle">Najbolje knjige samo kod nas!</div>
                        <div class="section_title">Sabskrajbujte se za 20% popusta!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row newsletter_container">
                <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="newsletter_form_container">
                        <form action="#">
                            <input type="email" class="newsletter_input" required="required" placeholder="E-mail here">
                            <button type="submit" class="newsletter_button">Subscribe</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both css,js,image file can't be found only in this page? That's so weird. Have you rebuild your project and try again? Or Try clearing your browser cache and reload the page to see if the updated files are now being loaded.

Comment: Yes it cannot be found only on this page. I've rebuild my project and deleted cache but it still does not work

Comment: It's so weird,  Have you tried to create a new view and try again?

Comment: Yea i did, but it does not work. I dont know what to do, I cant make more that 1 view on 1 controller this is crazy.

Comment: UPDATE: I solved the problem. I dont know why, but in this view when you have to type `src` or `href` values you need to type it like this: `<img src="/images/picture.jpg>`. On other views i typed it without the first / and it all worked fine